# Connect the windows kernel driver to physical serial port (COM1) in windows

Tags: windows, serial-port, kernel, driver

I need to connect my kernel driver in windows to com port (COM1) and I want to write some data on COM1, How can I do it? Need suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a Virtual Serial driver, here is Microsoft [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial2) for Kernel mode driver.

Keep in the middle that Windows allocates the COM numbers, depends on the number of ports that you have on your system. COM1 is usually allocated to the onboard serial port.

Comment: your link for virtual  serial port support kernel mode?

Comment: it is only Kernel Mode

Comment: I have first build `serial driver` and in `wdfserial` folder, three files generated `.cat .sys .inf`, how to make installer for setup for it and for `virtual serial`? thx a lot